# Trying to remove a certain character from a string until the string only has x number of characters

Tags: string, delphi

I'm trying to remove a certain character from a string until the string only has x number of characters

So what I would like to achieve is

```
c:\folder\new\stuff\all\more\hello\awesome\to.dll
```

becomes

```
c:\folder\new\
```

By deleting one character at a time until the string posses 3 x '\'

{or how ever many backslashes I require it to posses since it wont be the same every time.}

So far I have tried:

```
function RemoveLastPart(var s: string; I : integer): string;
begin
  repeat
    delete(s, length(s),1)
  until (pos ('\',s) = I) and (s[length(s)]='\');
  result := s;
end;
```

and

```
function RemoveStr(var s: string; I : integer): string;
 begin
   while (pos ('\',s) = I)  do
    begin
   delete(s, length(s),1);
   result := s;
 end
 end;
```

but this wouldn't work because your path could still be

```
c:\folder\new\stuff vs c:\folder\new\
```

I'm guessing I'm using `pos` incorrectly. I thought if a string posses '\' then do something.

Since I never know how long the path will be or what folders it may or may not contain , it makes it a bit tricky.

I have also tried `(pos ('\',s) < I)` and increasing I by 1

So if I wanted I to be 3 I would say (pos ('\',s) < 4)

edited..............

Thanks for all the reply's

I will never know how many backslashes it will need .... I have a source folder which changes all the time

I then have a destination folder which also changes all the time.
the source folder (E.G c:\test) and the destination folder (E.G D:\Search Results)

The source folder is scanned for file types .. once a matching type is found (E.G c:\test\somefolder\anotherfolder.exe) 
I replace the source with the destination 
(E.G D:\Search Results\somefolder\anotherfolder.exe).

I then use a function to count both the source folders backslashes and the 
search results backslashes so

D:\Search Results\ = two backslashes(2)
and
D:\Search Results\somefolder\anotherfolder.exe = four backslashes(4)

if we the take 4-2+1 = 3

this is where I am stuck ...

I now know how many backslashes I need to copy the whole source directory.

so I need 3 back slashes

if we count backwards we get

D:\Search Results\somefolder\anotherfolder.exe 
D:\Search Results\somefolder\anotherfolder (this is wrong, this is why I added `until (pos ('\',s) = I) and (s[length(s)]='\');` )

it would be better to count forwards so we get

D:\Search Results\somefolder\anotherfolder.exe 
D:\Search Results\somefolder\

thanks once again for all the replys. I haven't tried any of the suggested yet I will look into all of them and see if I can make something work.

Comment: Method Pos always returns position of the first ocurnace of the substring inside specific string. So in your example the Pos would always be returning 3 as a result. So I recomend you to use PosEx instead, becouse it allows you to specify the position from which forward does it search for your specific substring.

Comment: @SilverWarior, newer versions of Delphi has Pos overloads that mimics PosEx.

Comment: Hi Thanks, im running xe7 .. will give that a shot thanks ! @SilverWarior

Comment: Thanks Tlama am busy reading over it now. @TLama

Comment: Do you really want to delete characters or do you want to walk up the path?

Comment: Hi thanks Lu RD , I will edit my original post to help better explain what I am trying to achieve and Sir rufo I would need to delete characters. I will explain in the edit

Comment: You are trying to solve two different tasks in one step. Better to make them separate. First count the number of backslashes in the two paths, (like this: `count1 := path1.CountChar('\');`). Then use the function Tom provided.

Comment: Hi Thanks LU RD, I have implemented it into my code., I just needed to change PosEx to pos since im using xe7. awesome thank you guys so much for all the help. I will award the answer to silverwolf since he/she made so much effort explain how the code works. thank you guys so much I will test both functions and see which is faster since I will be scanning 1000s of directory's. @LURD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are only looking for specific characters you might also use another approach by simply iterating over all characters in string and counting how many times have you already found specific character.

Here is the code for achieving this;

```
//This function returns desired substring as result and thus does not modiffy input 
//string
//Use this function when it is required for your InputStr to remain intact for further
//processing
function ExtractSubString(InputStr: String; SearchedChar: Char; Count: Integer): String;
var Pos: Integer;
    TimesFound: Integer;
begin
  //Set initial values to local variables
  TimesFound := 0;
  //Set the default result of the method
  //While this is not needed with string results it is still good practice
  //Setting default result is required with most other result types so you don't
  //end up with uninitialized result which can have random value stored in it.
  Result := '';
  //Iterate through all characters in a string
  //NOTE: On moobile platforms strings are Zero-based so modiffy the code acordingly
  //to start with Pos 0
  for Pos := 1 to Length(InputStr) do
  begin
    //Check if specific character matches the one we are looking for
    if InputStr[Pos] = SearchedChar then
    begin
      //Increase the counter which stores how many times have we already found
      //desired character
      TimesFound := TimesFound+1;
      //Check if we found desirecd character enough times
      if TimesFound = Count then
      begin
        //Copy desired part of the input string to result
        Result := Copy(InputStr,0,Pos);
        //Use break command to break out of the loop prematurely
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;


//This procedure modifies existing string instead of making a new shortened string
//You need to provide existing string variable as InputStr parameter
//Use only if you need to process string only once othervise use ExtractSubstring
procedure ShortenString(var InputStr: String; SearchedChar: Char; Count: Integer);
var Pos: Integer;
    TimesFound: Integer;
begin
  //Set initial values to local variables
  TimesFound := 0;
  //Iterate through all characters in a string
  //NOTE: On moobile platforms strings are Zero-based so modiffy the code acordingly
  //to start with Pos 0
  for Pos := 1 to Length(InputStr) do
  begin
    //Check if specific character matches the one we are looking for
    if InputStr[Pos] = SearchedChar then
    begin
      //Increase the counter which stores how many times have we already found
      //desired character
      TimesFound := TimesFound+1;
      //Check if we found desirecd character enough times
      if TimesFound = Count then
      begin
        //Adjust the length of the string and thus leaving out all the characters 
        //after desired length
        SetLength(InputStr,Pos);
        //Use break command to break out of the loop prematurely
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi thank you SilverWarior. awesome works like a charm. thank you for going to so much detail and explaining everything so nicely.

Comment: Should be Copy(..., 0, ...) if you use 1-based strings

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide another approach which modifies existing string rather than returning a new copy of desired substring. NOTE: I have changed the name of old method to be more fitting to what it does. So you will need to modiffy your code that uses them since the old functions name is used for new procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Use `PosEx` repeatedly as many times as you want the backslash to occur in the result. When you have then found the *nth*, use `SetLength()` to chop the string, or `Copy()` if you want to preserve the original string and return the shortened string as a function result, e.g.:

```
function ChopAtNthBackslash(const s: string; n: integer):string;
var
  i, k: integer;
begin
  k := 0;
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    k := PosEx('\', s, k+1);
    if k < 1 then Exit('');
  end;
  Result := Copy(s, 1, k);
end;
```